# Cannot select element on DWR 921 Router management page

Tags: javascript, selenium

I'm trying to use Selenium in Python to send sms using my Dlink DWR-921 router. But I can't select any element on the `document`. I tried `td`, `table`, `body` but none of them works. I also tried on browser javascript for the above elements as well. Using `document.getElementsByTagName()`, but I get empty `HTMLCollection`. May I know why the element in the page is not selectable?

Update: To ensure the dom last been properly and fully loaded. I took a screenshot and confirmed that the DOM has been loaded everytime it run.
[image]
Router model: DLink DWR-921

SW Version: V01.01.3.016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to look for an **input** tag.

Also, it may be that the elements are inside an **Iframe**. Selenium doesn't "know" how to locate elements inside iframes, so you need to tell me to go into the iframe:

```
driver.switchTo().frame("firstframe");
```

or

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
```

Comment: The iframe method works! Thanks!